# Need a proof or counterexample?

Tags: measure-theory

I am reading about [Atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory)) in a space.Let $(\Omega,\Im)$ be a Boolean measurable space.

> Suppose $\vert \Im \vert < \infty$,then there are **finitely** many atoms such that every element of $\Im$ can be expressed as union of some of those atoms.

I know that the atoms can be formed as for any $x \in \Omega$ we define $B_x$ to be the intersection of all elements of $\Im$ which contains $x$ but we don't get the finiteness from here.Any proof/counterexample?

Comment: How many intersections of the elements of $\Im$, or their $\Omega$ complements, can there be if there are only finitely many elements of $\Im$ ?

Comment: @GrahamKemp Because all of these intersections are itself element of $\Im$ and they are disjoint.Hence they can only be finitely many right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $\mathfrak{F}=\{A_1,\ldots,A_n\}$ with $|\mathfrak{F}|=n<\infty$. For $f:\{1,\ldots,n\}\to \{0,1\}$, consider the set of the form

$$B_f=A_1^{f(1)}\cap \cdots \cap A_n^{f(n)}$$where $A_i^0=A_i$ and $A_i^1=\Omega\setminus A_i$.

Notice that $B_f\in \mathfrak{F}$ for any function $f$ (because $\mathfrak{F}$ is closed under complements and intersections), and whenever for every $i\leq n$ and $f:\{1,\ldots,n\}\to \{0,1\}$, either $A_i\cap B_f=\emptyset$ (when $f(i)=1$) or $B_f\subseteq A_i$ (when $f(i)=0$).

The element $B_f$ that are non-empty are the atoms, and since $\{B_f\}\subseteq \mathfrak{F}$, there are finitely many of them.

Finally, let us show that for any $i\leq n$, $A_i=\displaystyle{\bigcup_{f(i)=0}B_f}$:

Given $x\in A_i$, consider the function $f_x:\{1,\ldots,n\}\to \{0,1\}$ given by $$\text{$f_x(j)=0$ if and only if $x\in A_j$.}$$ It is clear that $x\in B_{f_x}$.

Comment: Dear @Wore:Sorry..is this obvious that $B_f$ are atoms?What is the "motivation" for defining $B_f$?

Comment: In my definition, $B$ is an atom if there is no $A$ such that $\emptyset\neq A\subsetneq B$. I just checked the definition you have in the link, and the only change is to consider those sets $B_f$ such that $\mu(B_f)>0$. [Notice that $B_f=\emptyset$ for several functions $f$, but we only consider those which are non-empty (or in your case, those which do have positive measure)]

Comment: So why it is clear by using your definition?

Comment: As I said in the answer, for every element $A_i\in\mathfrak{F}$ you either have $A_i\cap B_f=\emptyset$ (which happen exactly if $B_f$ is not empty and $f(i)=1$) or $B_f\subseteq A_i$ (which happen exactly when $f(i)=0$, since $A_i$ is one of the set in the intersection that generates $B_f$). These eliminates the possiblity of having $A_i\in \mathfrak{F}$ with $\emptyset\neq A_i\subsetneq B_f$